# Hiding flash component scrollbars using object/param syntax

Tags: javascript, html, flash

I'm not sure if this is possible (complete non-flash developer speaking), but we have a 3rd party component that we want to only show a certain topleft hand portion of.

I've tried limiting the size of the HTML object container as:

```
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="600" height="415" data="<url>">
    <param name="movie" value="<url>" />
    <param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
    <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always" />
    <param name="quality" value="high" />
    <param name="flashvars" value="<vars>" />
</object>
```

So limiting it to 600x415, but this causes horizontal and vertical scrollbars as part of the flash component to appear. Is there any standard way to override this behaviour?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if the scrollbars are "inside" the flash itself you best bet (if you can't change the flash application) is to make the containing div smaller instead of the actual flash embed, effectively masking out the part you want.